# How to let my FileProvider provide a file when another app sends an "open file" intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider

I have a `FileProvider` that can produce files which can be opened by other apps by sending an `ACTION_VIEW` intent with the file uri.

I'm wondering if the file provider can work in the other direction; another app asks to open a file - e.g. using [ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT) - and my app would then respond that it can provide a file with the given type.

I imagine a file picker where this "file" would be shown as an icon in a special folder or something, then when clicked the file provider would provide it as usual.

**Is this achievable?**

Comment: You want your Application to be listed in the popup right ?

Comment: Yes. And the FileProvider should provide a uri.

Comment: Do you know about Intent Filters ? They are exactly made for that purpose. Read this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters